# Yii2 sizeg/yii2-jwt how to access jwt claims?

Tags: yii2, jwt

Creating a JWToken with sizeg/yii2-jwt works. I can send it to the client. I get it back from the client with the next request, can validate the token and can access the user data from the token.

in My Apicontroller I have

```
$behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => \sizeg\jwt\JwtHttpBearerAuth::class,
            'except' => ['login', 'logout', 'password'],
        ];
```

In my user Model I have the code

```
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
{
    if (preg_match('=^\d{1,6}$=', $token->getClaim('user')->id)) {
        return new static($token->getClaim('user'));
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now in every controller I can access the user data with

```
Yii::$app->user->id
Yii::$app->user->name
```

But how can I access other claims made in the Token? I made other claims in the Token, for example I store the time difference between the local time on the user device (maybe in another timezone) and the server time in a claim 'tsDiff'. Of cource I could read and parse the token again

```
$token = Yii::$app->jwt->getParser()->parse((string) $jwtString); 
$token->getClaim('tsDiff');
```

But the Token was already parsed and validated for Authentication and it doesn't make much sense to do it twice. But I don't know how to access other claims anywhere in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can store result of token parsing in property of user model. Than you can get it through `Yii::$app->user->identity`.

User model

```php
class User extends Model implements IdentityInterface
{
    protected $token;

    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        if (preg_match('=^\d{1,6}$=', $token->getClaim('user')->id)) {
            $user = new static($token->getClaim('user'));
            $user->token = $token;
            return $user;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public function getToken()
    {
        return $this->token;
    }

    // ... other content of User model
}
```

Then you can access the token in your controller like this:

```php
public function actionMyAction()
{
    $user = Yii::$app->user->identity;
    if ($user instanceof \app\models\User) {
        $tsDiff = $user->token->getClaim('tsDiff');
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. But it seems I did not gave enough information.

class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface

Because of class user User extends ActiveRecord and not Model it seems every additional property, that is not part of the database table is not available.